# Find / display GPS coordinates based on the address or city and vice versa

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gps

I have a google map with a city field, address and GPS coordinates fields. I would like to find / display GPS coordinates from an entered address or vis versa. I would like to be able to display the data on the fields by moving the marker on the map.
I did geocoding and geocoding inverted but I can not get to position it at the indicated address. I can not move the marker by clicking on another area of the map.
Am I clear enough? Can you help me ? Here is my code:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="__CSS__/main.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        .content{width:600px; height: 350px;margin: 10px auto;}
        .content table{width: 100%}
        .content table td{vertical-align: middle;}
        #city,#address{height:21px;background: #FFF;border:1px solid #d7d7d7; line-height: 21px;}
        #city{width:60px}
        #address{width:130px}
        #is_dynamic_label span{vertical-align:middle;margin: 3px 0px 3px 3px;}
        #is_dynamic_label input{vertical-align:middle;margin: 3px 3px 3px 50px;}
    </style>
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="http://api.map.baidu.com/api?v=2.0&ak=021c8fdab28e1941b3649ff34d23cd05"></script>-->

    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyASjqBUWgtGv5RHh_jMYFxRJmYvrGhfRIc&callback=initMap">

    </script>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="__JS__/jquery.js"></script>
    <title>Affichage de la carte</title>
</head>
<body>





<div class="content">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td width="130"><var id="lang_city"></var>Ville：<input id="city" type="text" /></td>
            <td width="190"><var id="lang_address"></var>Adresse：<input id="address" type="text" value="" /></td>
            <td><input id ="submit" class="formInput01" type="button" value="Ok"></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Latitude：<a id="lat"></a></td>
            <td>Longitude：<a id="lng"></a></td>
            <td>Lieu actuelle：<a id="_address"></a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="hidden" value="{$_GET['id']}" name="id" id="id">
    <div style="width:100%;height:340px;margin:5px auto;border:1px solid gray" id="container"></div>

    <script>
     /* Déclaration des variables  */
        var geocoder;
        var map;
        var marker = null;
        var elevator;



        function initMap() {
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(48.866667, 2.333333);  // Paris
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('container'), {
                zoom: 8,
                center: latlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            });
            
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map,
              position: latlng
            });
            
            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            
            document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
             geocodeAddress(geocoder, map);
           });

        }
        
        function geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap) {
        var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
        geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
          if (status === 'OK') {
            resultsMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: resultsMap,
              position: results[0].geometry.location
            });
          } else {
            alert("Le geocodage n\'a pu etre effectue pour la raison suivante: " + status);
          }
        });
      }
      
      
      function geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map, infowindow) {
        var input = document.getElementById('latlng').value;
        var latlngStr = input.split(',', 2);
        var latlng = {lat: parseFloat(latlngStr[0]), lng: parseFloat(latlngStr[1])};
        geocoder.geocode({'location': latlng}, function(results, status) {
          if (status === 'OK') {
            if (results[1]) {
              map.setZoom(11);
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlng,
                map: map
              });
              infowindow.setContent(results[1].formatted_address);
              infowindow.open(map, marker);
            } else {
              window.alert('No results found');
            }
          } else {
            window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
          }
        });
      }
    </script>


</div>


<!--
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map = new BMap.Map("container"),marker,point,styleStr,
        lat = document.getElementById('lat'),
        lng = document.getElementById('lng'),
        _address = document.getElementById('_address'),
        id = document.getElementById('id');
    var api = frameElement.api, W = api.opener,
        _lat = W.document.getElementById('lat'),
        _lng = W.document.getElementById('lng'),
        p_address = W.document.getElementById('address');
    map.enableScrollWheelZoom();
    map.enableContinuousZoom();
    function doSearch(){
        if (!document.getElementById('city').value) {
            alert('Vous n\'avez pas entré  la ville！');
            return;
        }
        var search = new BMap.LocalSearch(document.getElementById('city').value, {
            onSearchComplete: function (results){
                if (results && results.getNumPois()) {
                    var points = [];
                    for (var i=0; i<results.getCurrentNumPois(); i++) {
                        points.push(results.getPoi(i).point);
                    }
                    if (points.length > 1) {
                        map.setViewport(points);
                    } else {
                        map.centerAndZoom(points[0], 13);
                    }
                    point = map.getCenter();
                } else {
                    alert(lang.errorMsg);
                }
            }
        });
        search.search(document.getElementById('address').value || document.getElementById('city').value);
    }

    function init(e){
        var geolocation = new BMap.Geolocation();
        map.centerAndZoom(new BMap.Point(116.404, 39.915), 11);  // 初始化地图,设置中心点坐标和地图级别
        map.addControl(new BMap.MapTypeControl());   //添加地图类型控件
        map.setCurrentCity("Paris"); // capital de France
        if(_lat.value && _lng.value){
            lat.innerHTML =  _lat.value;
            lng.innerHTML =  _lng.value;
            //
            var point = new BMap.Point(_lng.value,_lat.value);
            map.centerAndZoom(point, 18);
            var geoc = new BMap.Geocoder();
                geoc.getLocation(point, function(rs){
                    var addComp = rs.addressComponents;
                    _address.innerHTML =(addComp.province+ addComp.city+ addComp.district + addComp.street + addComp.streetNumber);
                });

            var marker = new BMap.Marker(point);// 创建标注
            map.addOverlay(marker);             // 将标注添加到地图中
        }else{
            geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(r){
                if(this.getStatus() == BMAP_STATUS_SUCCESS){
                    var mk = new BMap.Marker(r.point);
                    map.addOverlay(mk);
                    map.panTo(r.point);
                    map.centerAndZoom(new BMap.Point(r.point.lng, r.point.lat), 18);  // 初始化地图,设置中心点坐标和地图级别
                    map.addControl(new BMap.MapTypeControl());   //添加地图类型控件
                    map.setCurrentCity(r.address.city);
                }
                else {
                    map.centerAndZoom(new BMap.Point(116.404, 39.915), 11);  // 初始化地图,设置中心点坐标和地图级别
                    map.addControl(new BMap.MapTypeControl());   //添加地图类型控件
                    map.setCurrentCity("paris");  // capital de France
                }
            },{enableHighAccuracy: true});
        }



        var geoc = new BMap.Geocoder();

        map.addEventListener("click", function(e){
            map.clearOverlays();
            var pt = e.point;
            geoc.getLocation(pt, function(rs){
                var point = new BMap.Point(rs.point.lng,rs.point.lat);
                map.centerAndZoom(point, 18);
                var marker = new BMap.Marker(point);// 创建标注
                map.addOverlay(marker);             // 将标注添加到地图中
                lat.innerHTML =  rs.point.lat;
                lng.innerHTML =  rs.point.lng;
                _address.innerHTML = rs.address;
            });
        });
    }


    init();
    document.getElementById('address').onkeydown = function (evt){
        evt = evt || event;
        if (evt.keyCode == 13) {
            doSearch();
        }
    };
    api.button({
        id:'ok',
        name:'Ok',
        callback:function(){
            if(!lat.innerHTML && !lng.innerHTML){
                alert('Veuillez confirmer l\'adresse actuelle！');
                return false;
            }
            W.document.getElementById('lat').value = lat.innerHTML;
            W.document.getElementById('lng').value = lng.innerHTML;
        }
    });

</script>

--->


</body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refrain from posting your API key out in the public as this is not secure; It allows the possibility of third parties to use up your quota. I'd recommend redacting the API key from your sample code for security.

I believe I understand what you are trying to do from your description, and I believe I have accomplished it.

First, I noticed that you weren't setting draggable to true for the marker, this is why you aren't able to drag the marker.

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  map: map,
  draggable: true,
  position: latlng
});
```

You mentioned wanting the user to be able to display GPS coordinates from an entered address or vis versa. For this, I added an extra input field for GPS coordinates:

```
<td width="190"><var id="lang_gps"></var>GPS：<input id="gps" type="text" value="" /></td>
```

If you want the user to be able to enter either GPS coordinates or an address, you will need to add logic so that the app knows whether it is forward or reverse geocoding. To do this, I added a click listener to the GPS coordinate input and the address input. If a user clicks on the GPS textbox, the address textbox is cleared. If a user clicks on the address textbox, the GPS coordinates textbox is cleared:

```
document.getElementById("address").addEventListener("click", function(){
            document.getElementById("gps").value = "";
        });
document.getElementById("gps").addEventListener("click", function(){
            document.getElementById("address").value = "";
        });
```

When a user clicks the OK button to geocode, the app checks whether address textbox or gps textbox has a value and then does forward or reverse geocoding depending on which textbox has a value.

I also needed to add two more action listeners. One for when the marker is dragged, and one for when the marker's drag ended. These fill the fields telling where the current address and lat,lng is.

```
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'drag',function(event) {
            document.getElementById('lat').innerHTML = event.latLng.lat();
            document.getElementById('lng').innerHTML = event.latLng.lng();



        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'dragend',function(event) {
            document.getElementById('lat').innerHTML =event.latLng.lat();
            document.getElementById('lng').innerHTML =event.latLng.lng();
            geocoder.geocode({'location': marker.getPosition()}, function(results, status) {
              if (status === 'OK') {
                document.getElementById('_address').innerHTML = results[0].formatted_address;
                for(i = 0; i<results[0].address_components.length; i++){
                 if(results[0].address_components[i].types[0] === "locality"){
                  document.getElementById('city').value = results[0].address_components[i].long_name;
                 }
                }
              } else {
                window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
              }
            });
        });
```

Currently, the user can enter either an address or gps coordinates and then click the OK button. Once that is done, the Ville field, latitude field, longitude field, and Lieu actuelle gets updated. Ville shows the city, latitude shows the latitude, longitude shows the longitude, and Lieu actuelle shows the full address of the current marker location. The user can then drag the marker accordingly and the Ville, Latidue, Longitude, and Lieu actuelle fields will update accordingly.

I have this demonstrated on a JSFiddle that I will link below. Please note that I have redacted my API key for security, you will need to please input your own API key for the sample to work:

https://jsfiddle.net/4cd0hsxk/1/

I hope this helps!